# Magento2: Created Date search result wrong in french but right in English admin site

Tags: search, magento2.2.3, multi-language

I have create a custom module for creating the orders report.Add Created Date TO 2 FROM Filter its working fine in English language .
like :[image]
But when i change Interface Locale french :
[image]

Then created Date TO 2 from filters not working properly :
[image]

Please elaborate the issue.
i have add Created Date column

```
        $this->addColumn('created_at', ['header' => __('Created Date'), 'index' => 'created_at','type'=>'date','filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually date fields are stored in UTC timezone and showed on Grid by converting UTC to Store timezone.

> Eg:
>
> Date in UTC - 2019-05-13 23:30:00 (Database Timezone)
>
> Date in EST - 2019-05-13 19:30:00 (US Store Timezone)
>
> Date in France - 2019-05-14 1:30:00 (France Store Timezone)

As you can see for the above record Date for US & UTC timezone remains same, but it changes for France since France is GMT+2, hence record created after 22:00 time goes to next date in France.

This could be issue with your module.

Comment: how can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: i also have checked using next day date but still no record found.